# Swap selected block of code upward/downward?

Tags: vimscript

I want to write a Vim Script which can achieve the following function, which is my favorite feature in some IDE. Say I have the following example code:

```
I'm a line and I just stay here.
I'm another line and I also stay here.

I'm the line to be selected and swapped upward 1.    (1)
I'm the line to be selected and swapped upward 2.    (2)
```

Then I can move the cursor to line `(1)` and `Vj` to select both `(1), (2)`, then now I can hold some custom key combination, say  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>option</kbd>  + <kbd>k</kbd>, and I hit these combination twice, then the expected result will be:

```
I'm the line to be selected and swapped upward 1.    (3)
I'm the line to be selected and swapped upward 2.    (4)
I'm a line and I just stay here.
I'm another line and I also stay here.
                                                     (1)
                                                     (2)
```

(The idea of swap selected lines downward is similar so I skip it.)

To avoid re-invent the wheel, is there any plugin already done this feature for us? If not, what are required for me to learn to write the above function?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many plugins to move lines of text to mention them here.

An example to exchange (move) selected lines, more or less like in `tpope/vim-unimpaired`:

```
xnoremap <expr><silent>[e printf(":move '<--%d<CR>gv", v:count1)
xnoremap <expr><silent>]e printf(":move '>+%d<CR>gv", v:count1)
```

So `[count][e` moves selection by `[count]` lines up, and `[count]]e` moves down.

Of course, you can do the same simply by selecting block and then typing `:m N`, where `N` is the number of line to put the block after.

Also, to swap two adjacent `:h paragraph`(s) quickly: `dap}p` or `dap2{p`. Creating a mapping that also accepts count is left as an excercise.

Answer (score 1):

[My own mappings](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/bubble.vim) for this purpose:

```
" Bubble single lines up and down
nnoremap - :.move +1<CR>
nnoremap _ :.move -2<CR>
" Bubble lines up and down in visual mode
vnoremap - :'<,'>move '>+1 \| normal! gv<CR>
vnoremap _ :'<,'>move '<-2 \| normal! gv<CR>
```